# Determine P(N1 = k1, N2 = k2, . . . , Nn = kn|NI = k).

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let Ni denote the number of car arrivals in an interval Ii = (ti
, ti + ci
]. Suppose we have n
such intervals, i = 1, 2, . . . , n, mutually disjoint and assume that Ni
’s are independent with
Ni ∼ P o(ciλ), that is, Poisson distribution with parameter ciλ. Denote the union of these
intervals by I, and their total length by c = c1 + c2 + · · · + cn. Given ki ≥ 0 and with
k = k1 + k2 + · · · + kn, determine P(N1 = k1, N2 = k2, . . . , Nn = kn|NI = k).

Answer (score 0):

Given,k=Σ_(i=1)^n k_i,c=Σ_(i=1)^n c_i

N¬i ~ Poi(c¬_i λ)  ,i=1,2,3,…,n.
=>Σ_(i=1)^n N_i=N_I  ~ Poi(Σ_(i=1)^n c_i λ)≡Poi(cλ)
Then    P(N=k)=(e^(-cλ)*(cλ)^k)/k!
Now,
P(N_1=k_1,N_2=k_2,…,N_n=k_n )=Π_(i=1)^n P(N_i=k_i )     ( As all N_i^' s are mutually disjoint and independent)
=>P(N_1=k_1,N_2=k_2,…,N_n=k_n  | N=k )=P(N_1=k_1  ⋂▒〖N_2=k_2  ⋂▒〖… ⋂▒〖N_n=k_n  ⋂▒〖N=k〗〗〗〗)/P(N=k)

P(N_1=k_1  ⋂▒〖N_2=k_2  ⋂▒〖… ⋂▒〖N_n=k_n  ⋂▒〖N=k〗〗〗〗)=
P(N_1=k_1 ).P(N_2=k_2│N_1=k_1 ).P(N_3=k_3│N_1=k_1∩N_2=k_2 )…P(N_I=k|P(N_1=k_1  ⋂▒〖N_2=k_2  ⋂▒〖… ⋂▒〖N_n=k_n 〗〗〗)

=> P(N_1=k_1  ⋂▒〖N_2=k_2  ⋂▒〖… ⋂▒〖N_n=k_n  ⋂▒〖N=k〗〗〗〗)=P(N_1=k_1 ).P(N_2=k_2 )…P(N_n=k_n ).1
If N_i^  〖= k〗*i,i=1,2,…n,then N_I=k=Σ*(i=1)^n k_i.
So,
P(N_I=k|P(N_1=k_1  ⋂▒〖N_2=k_2  ⋂▒〖… ⋂▒〖N_n=k_n 〗〗〗) = 1
Therefore,
P(N_1=k_1,N_2=k_2,…,N_n=k_n  | N=k )=(Π_(i=1)^n P(N_i=k_i ))/P(N_I=k) =(k!.Π_(i=1)^n c_i^(k_i ))/(Π_(i=1)^n k_i !)  = k! .Π_(i=1)^n  (ci/c)^(k_i )/(k_i !)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: (Okay, I wrote this in unicode equation editor of ms word. Only after pasting i got to know that its not accepting it. )

Comment: So, The question boils down to (product of P(Ni = ki)) / P(N = k) .